# Calculate a function result with a variable in PHP

Tags: php, function, variables

I have a function that calculates something and want to subtract the result from the variable $bebebe. The result $bebebe only shows the first variable being $testNew. It doesn't show the $testNew-$testest2. Any ideas?

```
<?php
function testEst() {
    if($_POST["maxkwhresultaat"] > 0){
        echo "" . $_POST['totaal'] . "";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "" . $_POST['maxkwh'] . "</p>";
    }
}
testEst();
?>

<?php
$testest2 = testEst();
$testNew = $_POST["totaal"];
$bebebe = $testNew-$testest2;
?>
    Result: <?php echo $bebebe?>
```

Comment: Your function just echoes out a value, it does not return it. So `$testest2` is not what you think it is.

Comment: You are not returning a value from testEst(), just creating output. Why are you calling testEst(); after its definition? What is in $_POST["totaal"] and $_POST["maxkwhresultaat"]? Just echo them to inspect.

Comment: @aynber So how do I get a result from the function as a variable that I can use? Sorry I'm new and still learning.

Comment: So how do I get a result from the function as a variable that I can use? Sorry I'm new and still learning. @ErwinMoller

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

Comment: @Lawonama You return a value from a function by using the return word. eg: return 23; returns 23 from that function. Read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php